# error while running the opencv python hand tracking module

Tags: python, cvzone

I'm learning Opencv-Python and i was following a tutorial of Hand Tracking Module from Murtaza's Workshop - Robotics and AI

here is the code I wrote in Pycharm Community Edition (if that helps):

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time

class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

    def FindHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
        #print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)

        if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms,
                                            self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        return img

                #for id, lm in enumerate(handLms.landmark):
                    #print(id,lm)
                    #h, w, c = img.shape
                    #cx, cy = int(lm.x*w), int(lm.y*h)
                    #print(id, cx, cy)
                    #if id==4:
                    #cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 10, (255,0,255), cv2.FILLED)


def main():
        pTime = 0
        cTime = 0

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        detector = handDetector()
        while True:
            success, img = cap.read()
            img = detector.FindHands(img)

            cTime = time.time()
            fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
            pTime = cTime

            cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255, 0, 255), 3)

            cv2.imshow('image', img)
            cv2.waitKey(1)

if __name__=="__main__":
        main()
```

and her is the error I get when I run the code:

```
 INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gouri/PycharmProjects/opencv/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
NameError: name 'results' is not defined
[ WARN:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

pls tell me how I can fix it
I want to complete it within 4 days
please

Comment: worked for me? something could be wrong with your mediapipe instalation?

Comment: worked for me too. What is your python version? what results when you uncomment the line `#print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)` gives?

Comment: What if it does not detect any hands?

Answer (score 0):

In your HandDetector Object, in FindHands, You must replace the line:

```
results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
```

to:

```
self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
```

And you should change all the 'results' to 'self.results'

Thanks.